# Setting Rule to run on Merge Request disable previous jobs and stages

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am learning Gitlab CI. Any help would be much appreciated!

I am trying to run the job `deploy review` on merge request. Here is a snippet:

```yaml
deploy review:
  stage: deploy review
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event' # <---- this rule somehow disable preceding stages
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    url: http://helloworld-$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG.surge.sh
  script:
    - surge --project public --domain $STAGING_DOMAIN
```

***I expect stages to be `build` -> `test` -> `deploy review`. However, when I add that rule line in `deploy review` job, my previous `build` and `test` jobs do not run***. I either have to add that rule to both `build` and `test` or remove it from `deployo review` to have both `build` and `test` run again.

Here is my full `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
image: node:lts-alpine

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy review # <----- I want this stage to run only on merge request
  - deploy staging
  - deploy production
  - production tests

variables: 
  STAGING_DOMAIN: unique-random-tri-staging.surge.sh
  PRODUCTION_DOMAIN: unique-random-tri.surge.sh

cache:
  key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  paths:
    - node_modules

build static website:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - npm install
    - npm i -g gatsby-cli
    - gatsby build
    - sed -i "s/%%VERSION%%/$CI_COMMIT_SHA/g" public/index.html
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "public"

test artifacts:
  image: alpine
  stage: test
  script:
    - grep -q "Gatsby" public/index.html

test website:
  stage: test
  script:
    - apk --no-cache add curl
    - npm i
    - npm i -g gatsby-cli
    - gatsby serve &
    - sleep 10
    - curl "http://localhost:9000" | tac | tac | grep -q "Gatsby"

deploy review:
  stage: deploy review
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event' # <---- this excludes build and test on merge request
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    url: http://helloworld-$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG.surge.sh
  script:
    - surge --project public --domain $STAGING_DOMAIN

deploy staging:
  stage: deploy staging
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: http://$STAGING_DOMAIN
  rules:
   - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == 'master'
  script:
    - npm i -g surge
    - surge --project public --domain $STAGING_DOMAIN

deploy production:
  stage: deploy production
  environment:
    name: production
    url: http://PRODUCTION_DOMAIN
  rules:
   - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == 'master'
  # when: manual
  # allow_failure: false
  script:
    - npm i -g surge
    - surge --project public --domain $PRODUCTION_DOMAIN

production test:
  stage: production tests
  image: alpine
  rules:
   - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == 'master'
  script:
    - apk add curl
    - curl "PRODUCTION_DOMAIN" | cat | grep "A great place"

  # yes
```

This is my Merge Request
[image]

This is my pipeline, notice it only has 1 job `deploy review`, intead of `buil` -> `test` -> `deploy review`

[image]

Comment: I have this same issue happening in my Merge Request pipeline. Did you find any resolution to the problem?

Comment: no sorry it's been a long time and i don't even remember this problem